# Spring batch configures global transactions

Tags: spring-batch

Does the latest version support the configuration of job-level transactions, that is, transactions between steps and chunks are no longer independent, but global unified transactions.

For example, when using chunks, if an exception occurs in a certain chunk, all chunks will be rolled back, including the submitted ones, or when a job contains multiple steps, if an exception occurs in one of the steps, the entire job will be rolled back.

I have tried the following configurations, but to no avail

```java
    @Bean
    public Job readAirTicketDetailJob(JobRepository jobRepository, DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager) {
        DefaultTransactionDefinition transactionDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
        TransactionStatus transaction = dataSourceTransactionManager.getTransaction(transactionDefinition);
        return new JobBuilder("readAirTicketDetailJob", jobRepository)
                .listener(jobExecutionListener)
                // .flow(readAirTicketDetailStep(jobRepository, dataSourceTransactionManager)).on("FAILED").to(rollbackStep(jobRepository, dataSourceTransactionManager)).end()
                .start(readAirTicketDetailStep(jobRepository, dataSourceTransactionManager))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step readAirTicketDetailStep(JobRepository jobRepository, DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager) {
        return new StepBuilder("readAirTicketDetailStep", jobRepository)
                // .transactionManager(null)
                // .listener(myTestStepExecutionListener)
                .<CtripAirTicketDetail, CtripAirTicketDetail>chunk(10, dataSourceTransactionManager)
                .reader(airTicketDetailItemReader(null))
                .processor(airTicketItemProcessor)
                .writer(airTicketDetailItemWriter())
                .transactionAttribute(new DefaultTransactionAttribute(Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED.value()))
                // .listener(airTicketWriteListener)
                .listener(airTicketChunkListener)
                // .transactionManager(lessTransactionManager())
                .build();
    }


@Component
public class CtripJobExecutionListener extends JobExecutionListenerSupport {

    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does the latest version support the configuration of job-level transactions

> For example, when using chunks, if an exception occurs in a certain chunk, all chunks will be rolled back, including the submitted ones, or when a job contains multiple steps, if an exception occurs in one of the steps, the entire job will be rolled back.

No, there are no job-level transactions in Spring Batch.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Then can I not use the springbatch transaction, such as opening the transaction before the job is executed, and commit or rollback the transaction according to the result after the job is executed. I tried to use `ResourcelessTransactionManager` and manually open the transaction as described above, but he prompted me `Existing transaction detected in JobRepository. Please fix this and try again (e.g. remove @Transactional annotations from client)` . What should I do.